# How to remove extra space for the 'print' command in python?

Tags: python

I'm new to python, I'm using v2.7

```
#Filename:ReverseNumber.py
data=int(raw_input("Enter any number: "))
print "Reverse of the number: ",
while data!=0:
    a=data%10
    print a,
    data=data/10
```

So the output should come like :

```
Enter any number: 123
Reverse of the number: 321
```

but instead of this in the second line it is printing one extra space before every number.

How to overcome this?

Comment: Why not simply `print str(data)[::-1]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could modify your approach in a number of ways:

Create a list of your values, then join them with a blank string for printing:

```
out = []
while data != 0:
  out.append(data % 10)
  data /= 10
print ''.join(map(str, out))
```

You could skip the whole integer conversion step and just reverse the incoming string:

```
data = '123'
print data[-1::-1]
```

You could skip the integer step and join the result of reversed:

```
data = '123'
print ''.join(reversed(data))
```

You could add a `backspace` to your print commands for your numbers:

```
while data != 0:
  print '\b%d' % (data % 10)
  data /= 10
```

Hopefully one of those fits your requirements.

Comment: In your first solution, `map(str, out)` is more concise and a bit faster.

Comment: @ChrisWong - Very true.  Thanks!  I've edited it to reflect this suggestion.  :)

Answer (score 2):

There is an implicit space when `a` is printed.

From the python docs:

"**A space is written before each object is (converted and) written**, unless the output system believes it is positioned at the beginning of a line. This is the case (1) when no characters have yet been written to standard output, (2) when the last character written to standard output is a whitespace character except ' ', or (3) when the last write operation on standard output was not a print statement."

So try

```
print "Reverse of the number:",
```

Comment: While this would eliminate the extra space before the number(s), it would not have addressed the spaces between numbers in the approach he described initially.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to not print it until you're ready to print the whole lot. Sample code follows using strings:

```
data = int (raw_input ("Enter any number: "))
if data == 0:
    str = "0"
else:
    str = ""
    while data != 0:
        str = "%s%d" % (str, data % 10)
        data = data / 10
print "Reverse of the number: %s" % (str)
```

Answer (score -2):

Make a empty variable for purpose of storing reversed number, append every digit to it in a loop and then do the printing.

```
a = ''
while data!=0:
    a += data%10
    data=data/10
print a
```

Comment: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: But here I'll get "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects"

Comment: Whoops, I haven't been in python for some time now, sorry for the TypeError. Although, the concept was fine, wasn't it?